# Why am I getting this 404 error with axios.post()? Using Express/Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, nodemailer

I'm trying to make a contact form with Nodemailer (first time), and I'm running into a 404 error.

I hope this isn't an obnoxious amount of code to share, I'll try to trim it down as much as I can.

***Server.js***

```
 const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.ethereal.email",
    port: 587,
    secure: false, 
    auth: {
        user: creds.USER, // Generated by ethereal
        pass: creds.PASS // Generated by ethereal
    }
});


transporter.verify((err, success) => {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err)
    } else {
        console.log("Server is ready to take messages")
    }
})

router.post("/send", (req, res, next) => {
    let name = req.body.name
    let email = req.body.email
    let message = req.body.message
    let content = `name: ${name} \n email: ${email} \n message: ${message}`


    let mail = {
        from: name,
        to: "jlbroughton88@gmail.com",
        subject: "Test from contact form",
        text: content
    }

    transporter.sendMail(mail, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            res.json({
                msg: "Message failed"
            })
        } else {
            res.json({
                msg: "Message succeeded!"
            })
        }
    })
})
```

***ContactForm.js (React Component)***

I've trimmed the JSX part, the submit trigger works fine. It breaks once it reaches the axios.post() method.

```
    handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    const email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    const message = document.getElementById('message').value;
    axios.post("http://localhost:3002/send", {
        name,
        email,
        message
    })
    .then((response) => {
        // console.log(response)
        if (response.data.msg === 'success') {
            alert("Message Sent.");
            this.resetForm()
        } else if (response.data.msg === 'fail') {
            alert("Message failed to send.")
        }
    })
}

resetForm() {
    document.getElementById('contact-form').reset();
}
```

Comment: Just by looking at your code, Make sure your server is running on `port 3002`. 404 is a `Not Found` error which means `axios` can't find your server. it's just a guess  but try removing `http://` from your post request an make sure `CORS` is enabled

Comment: @ShivamSood thanks for the response. I enabled CORS but i still get the 404 error even if I use port 5007 for axios instead of 3002. In my error response, the config data shows my input data and the correct headers, but the root request is all null...Any thoughts?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to post error logs! Might find something suspicious there. and I'm assuming you are using `Express` so on which port are you listening there? `app.listen()`

Comment: Sure thing. yeah i'm using express and listening on port 5007.

Comment: Sorry about the cluttered response there, hopefully, it's legible. I wasn't allowed to post all of it as it exceeded the character limit. Hopefully whats there is enough.

Comment: You can edit the post and add it there for more readability! Thanks

Comment: Okay i believe this should work. https://gist.github.com/jlbroughton88/a79752d67b5a0ed6d0710eea15804d4a

Comment: Any particular reason of making post request to `3002` when your server is running at `5007`?